# Explorator Tests in Visual Studio 2015 is empty after install Update 3

Tags: visual-studio

I installed update 3 for my vs community and i see in my projects, theres no tests lists in test's exlporator. The window is always empty. I reinstall vs and there's no help. Is it whats wrong with update 3 or my PC?

Comment: Do you mean the "Test Explorer" panel? Do you rebuild your solution?

Comment: I'm press F5 and i'm run my app. Then i press Test->Run all tests and tests will run, but in Test Exlporer i cant see anything.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not an answer. Answers are for answers they are not for
>   adding details to the question. When you have more information for
>   your question then please edit it into the question. Use the "Edit"
>   link just below the question. – AdrianHHH 6 hours ago

Sorry i'm beginner ;)

Thanks for help. The problem is known for Microsoft, they're working on it.
For now, we must do that:

> If we rename the
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Core.resources.dll" to
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Core.resources.dll.bak" in the
>   folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\de" we can see at least the tests in the explorer (with banner).

This is the problem for VS who have installed language pack.